# Extracting data from multiple excel files using R

Tags: r, excel, extract

I have many excel files in a folder that has similar structure:
[image]

I would like to output it to something like that:
[image]

This is what I have tried. While I am able to extract the range of cells in B15:G17, how can I append the cell B8 in a column? Also, possible to have row 10 as the column header?

```
library("readxl")

file.list <- list.files(path=".", pattern=".xlsx")

df.list <- lapply(file.list, read_excel, sheet=1, range=("B15:G17"), col_names=FALSE, col_types = NULL)
df <- data.frame(df.list)
```

Comment: You can use `skip` argument to skip the rows from 1 to 9

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `read.xlsx` from `openxlsx` is a bit more flexible as we can specify the `rows/cols` argument to read a particular cell as well as use `startRow` to specify the starting row

```
library(openxlsx)
lst1 <- lapply(file.list, function(x) read.xlsx(x, sheet = 1, startRow = 10, cols = 3:6, rows = 15:17))
```

Also, read the specific cell separately, and then bind it as a new column 'ID' in each datasets of the `list` with `Map` and `cbind`

```
lst2 <- lapply(file.list, function(x) setNames(read.xlsx(x, sheet = 1,
       rows = 8, cols = 2), 'ID'))

Map(cbind, ID = lst2, lst1)
```

Comment: that kind of work, but how do I append the contents in cell B8 as a new column? And somehow the column header did not appear

Comment: @Jane Regarding the column names, by default `colNames = TRUE` and `If TRUE, the first row of data will be used as column names`,  So if the column name row is on 10 th row, then you can change the `rows = 10:17`

Comment: for the column names, i did try `colNames = TRUE` and even included `fillMergedCells = TRUE` but somehow it is not picking up.

Comment: For the ID part, I encountered the following error for lst2 `Error in names(object) <- nm : attempt to set an attribute on NULL
In addition: Warning message:
No data found on worksheet. ` Likely that some of the files have missing ID?

Comment: @Jane. Can you check `lapply(lst1, dim)`. May be some files are not getting read?

Comment: oh yes, there are some dataframes in lst1 with different number of columns. is there a workaround for this? `Map(cbind, ID = lst2, lst1)`

Comment: @Jane The `Map` should still work for that case.  It would be an issue only if some 'lst1' are empty.  Can you please confirm that

Comment: there are data frames in lst1 with empty rows, can these be skipped such that the Map will work?

Comment: @Jane You can get the index of those elements i.e. `i1 <- sapply(lst2, nrow) >0; Map(cbind, ID = lst2[i1], lst1[i1])`